# Error During PingFederate Agentless Sequence

Tags: pingfederate

Some of our users are encountering the following error page during the sequence of redirects after authenticating at their IdP.

```
"Unexpected exception occurred in Response Handling: null"
Partner: ...
Target: ...
```

This is what I believe is the corresponding info from the the server log.

```
2015-07-16 07:48:53,458  DEBUG [com.pingidentity.jgroups.MuxInvocationHandler] invocation of saveState on InterReqStateMgmtMapImpl state map size:215 attributes map size4 w/args: [ZkyN3LwNSjurZyfIewu1Kgjbgl7HrB, State(1437050933419){
inMsgCtx=null
outMsgCtx=OutMessageContext
XML: <samlp:AuthnRequest Version="2.0" ID="E6_0yldGrt0iqNKfUpArog6DG8G" IssueInstant="2015-07-16T12:48:53.419Z" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">#issuer%</saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true"/>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
entityId: <Id> (IDP)
Binding: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect
relayState: ZkyN3LwNSjurZyfIewu1Kgjbgl7HrB
Endpoint: <endpoint>
SignaturePolicy: DO_NOT_SIGN

parameters=null}] returned null
```

Is there an obvious place to look for more details? This happens for around 10% of our users and seems to follow them from device to device.

Comment: I think looking at a HTTP Header trace might be more helpful or the full server.log. This snippet doesn't provide enough info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was. We are using account linking using the SAML Subject from the IdP. It turned out that a number of accounts at the IdP didn't have the LDAP attribute mapped to the NameID populated. So we were receiving SAML assertions without any data in the Subject.

Understanding where to look is the key. The audit.log file shows a general "failure". Then you look up corresponding activity details in the server.log file. Then you examine the corresponding SAML assertion in the log to determine what the problem was. The difficult part is noticing omissions in the data. That's harder for the eye/brain to catch imho.

It would be useful if we had an option for directing users to a custom page rather than a Ping-specific error page when this occurs.